# Python - Pandas - Convert YYYYMM to datetime

Tags: python, pandas

Beginner python (and therefore pandas) user. I am trying to import some data into a pandas dataframe. One of the columns is the date, but in the format "YYYYMM". I have attempted to do what most forum responses suggest:

```
df_cons['YYYYMM'] = pd.to_datetime(df_cons['YYYYMM'], format='%Y%m')
```

This doesn't work though (`ValueError: unconverted data remains: 3`). The column actually includes an additional value for each year, with MM=13. The source used this row as an average of the past year. I am guessing `to_datetime` is having an issue with that.

Could anyone offer a quick solution, either to strip out all of the annual averages (those with the last two digits "13"), or to have `to_datetime` ignore them?

Comment: Have you tried to parse it while importing your data? For instance if you read a csv with `read_csv` in pandas, you have an argument which is `parse_dates = [your_col_name]`

Answer (score 12, accepted):

pass `errors='coerce'` and then `dropna` the `NaT` rows:

```
df_cons['YYYYMM'] = pd.to_datetime(df_cons['YYYYMM'], format='%Y%m', errors='coerce').dropna()
```

The duff month values will get converted to `NaT` values

```
In[36]:
pd.to_datetime('201613', format='%Y%m', errors='coerce')

Out[36]: NaT
```

Alternatively you could filter them out before the conversion

```
df_cons['YYYYMM'] = pd.to_datetime(df_cons.loc[df_cons['YYYYMM'].str[-2:] != '13','YYYYMM'], format='%Y%m', errors='coerce')
```

although this could lead to alignment issues as the returned Series needs to be the same length so just passing `errors='coerce'` is a simpler solution

Comment: Awesome thanks. It looks like the `.dropna()` didn't actually drop the `NaT` rows for me, but I think I can figure that part out.

Comment: You may need to do that as a separate step, so after assignment then call `dropna()`

Answer (score 0):

Clean up the dataframe first.

```
df_cons = df_cons[~df_cons['YYYYMM'].str.endswith('13')]
df_cons['YYYYMM'] = pd.to_datetime(df_cons['YYYYMM'])
```

May I suggest turning the column into a period index if YYYYMM column is unique in your dataset.

First turn YYYYMM into index, then convert it to monthly period.

```
df_cons = df_cons.reset_index().set_index('YYYYMM').to_period('M')
```