# graph with multiple lines python dataframe

Tags: python, dataframe, matplotlib, graph

I have a dataframe where I want to create a line graph. I want 1 line per category and on the `x` axis I want the date, on `y` the 12MKG. I dont know how to put labels on the lines and make the lines different colours per categorie.

So far I have tried:

```
plt.plot(df['date'],datatoplot['12MKG'])
```

| date | categorie | 12MKG |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 202001 | cat1 | 0.9836956 |
| 202002 | cat1 | 0.9836956 |
| 202003 | cat1 | 0.9831461 |
| 202004 | cat1 | 0.97206706 |
| 202005 | cat1 | 0.9698492 |
| 202006 | cat1 | 0.97630334 |
| 202007 | cat1 | 0.9787234 |
| 202008 | cat1 | 0.9810606 |
| 202009 | cat1 | 0.9825784 |
| 202010 | cat1 | 0.98165137 |
| 202011 | cat1 | 0.9768116 |
| 202012 | cat1 | 0.96666664 |
| 202101 | cat1 | 0.9655172 |
| 202102 | cat1 | 0.95214105 |
| 202103 | cat1 | 0.93721974 |
| 202104 | cat1 | 0.9419087 |
| 202105 | cat1 | 0.93158954 |
| 202106 | cat1 | 0.9189189 |
| 202107 | cat1 | 0.9144603 |
| 202001 | cat2 | 0.3118644 |
| 202002 | cat2 | 0.3006993 |
| 202003 | cat2 | 0.3017544 |
| 202004 | cat2 | 0.29433963 |
| 202005 | cat2 | 0.3030303 |
| 202006 | cat2 | 0.30483273 |
| 202007 | cat2 | 0.33206108 |
| 202008 | cat2 | 0.33730158 |
| 202009 | cat2 | 0.344 |
| 202010 | cat2 | 0.34008098 |
| 202011 | cat2 | 0.34051725 |
| 202012 | cat2 | 0.3224299 |
| 202101 | cat2 | 0.33027524 |
| 202102 | cat2 | 0.3187773 |
| 202103 | cat2 | 0.29338843 |
| 202104 | cat2 | 0.28458497 |
| 202105 | cat2 | 0.2804878 |
| 202106 | cat2 | 0.2804878 |
| 202107 | cat2 | 0.2631579 |

kind regards,

wokter

Comment: Please provide what you have tried so far.

Comment: [Convert to dates](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45215525/python-pandas-convert-yyyymm-to-datetime)?

Comment: @Xitiz plt.plot(df['date'],datatoplot['12MKG'])

Comment: Put that in question not in comment!

Answer (score 0):

Assuming I have understood your question correct there are many ways of doing this. One way is to cycle through each category and adding each line with a predetermined color. You can skip the color dict part if you want to use the default colormap. It is even possible to use colormaps to get a specific color 'theme'.

```
#If you want to control the color
color_dict = {'cat1': 'r',
              'cat2': 'b'}


fig, ax = plt.subplots(1,1)

# Cycle over the categories
for cat in df['categorie'].unique():
    # get the data for the relevant category
    temp = df[df['categorie']==cat]
    # plot the line using the 'label' keyword to add a label and 'color'
    # to control the color 
    ax.plot(temp['date'], temp['12MKG'], label=cat, color=color_dict[cat])

ax.legend()
```