# Python Pandas to convert datetime format from 'MM/DD/YYYY hh:mm:ss' to 'YYYY-MM-DDThh:mm:ssZ'

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, date, datetime

I'm trying to convert one of the Column in CSV which is for Date/timestamp in the format **12/30/2023 22:13** to a required format **2023-12-30T22:13:39Z**.

So far got this:

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.read_csv('input.csv', na_filter=False, skiprows=0)
print(df)
df['datetime'] = pd.to_datetime(df['datetime'])
print(df)
```

This gets me Date/time in format of **2023-12-30 22:13:00**.

There is a '*format*' in to_datetime() documentation (https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.to_datetime.html), Tried this but this does not work.

```
df['datetime'] = pd.to_datetime(df['datetime'], format='%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%sZ', errors='coerce')
```

This [Python - Pandas - Convert YYYYMM to datetime](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45215525/python-pandas-convert-yyyymm-to-datetime) closet I found to what I needed but cannot make it work.

Please someone help.

input.csv
[image]

Tried:
[image]

Comment: `pd.to_datetime(df['datetime'], dayfirst=False).dt.strftime('%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%sZ')` the format to pass to `to_datetime` is the input format, not the desired one.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Convert Pandas Column to DateTime](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26763344/convert-pandas-column-to-datetime)

Comment: @mozway This works great, on test csv file. But when I used on production input file which few thousand rows long, I found it failing with this error because it didn't like the format: 
```
raise ParserError("Unknown string format: %s", timestr)
dateutil.parser._parser.ParserError: Unknown string format: =abc xyz on mm/dd/yyyy, NUM31 days
```
Is there way to ignore if something doesn't follow format? Thank you.

Comment: Add `errors='coerce'`

Answer (score 1):

Using Regular expression `re` with `csv`

Input.csv

```
datetime
12/30/2023 22:13
9/17/2023 6:55
9/1/2023 23:59
7/5/2023 23:59
3/5/2023 14:56
5/9/2023 8:32
```

Code

```py
import csv
import re

with open('input.csv') as csv_file:
    csv_reader = csv.reader(csv_file)
    next(csv_reader)
    for row in csv_reader:
        print(row[0])
        date_pattern = "(\d{1,2})\/(\d{1,2})\/(\d{4})\s(\d{1,2})\:(\d{2})"
        r = re.match(date_pattern, row[0])
        new_date = '{0}-{1}-{2}T{3}:{4}:00Z'.format(r[3], r[1], r[2], r[4], r[5])
        print(new_date)
        print('--------------------')
```

Result

```
$ python convert-csv.py
12/30/2023 22:13
2023-12-30T22:13:00Z
--------------------
9/17/2023 6:55
2023-9-17T6:55:00Z
--------------------
9/1/2023 23:59
2023-9-1T23:59:00Z
--------------------
7/5/2023 23:59
2023-7-5T23:59:00Z
--------------------
3/5/2023 14:56
2023-3-5T14:56:00Z
--------------------
5/9/2023 8:32
2023-5-9T8:32:00Z
--------------------
```

[Regexper](https://regexper.com/) Visualization

[image]

[regex101](https://regex101.com/) test matched strings

[image]